# how to use repeater iteratively?

Tags: c#

I have one repeater which displays the list of puja.i have also used one datalist to display the names of temples.whenever i click on search it displays only the last value of the repeater i.e it is taking only the last value of the repeater....my question is how to use loop inside a repeater???
here is my code behind how i used datalist and repeater:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //lblnodatafound.Visible = true;
        //lbldatafound.Visible = false;
        if (Request.QueryString["search"] != null)
        {
            var dt = new DataTable("Data");
            String source = Request.QueryString["search"];
            var splitseparator = new string[] { " " };
            String[] result = source.Split(splitseparator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach (String s in result)
            {
                if (IsAlphaNumeric(s) == true)
                {
                    var dttemp = new DataTable();
                    dttemp = fnsearch(s);
                    dt.Merge(dttemp, true);
                }
            }
            if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
            {


                    int count = dt.Rows.Count;
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        DataList1.DataSource = dt;
                        DataList1.DataBind();

                        lblnodatafound.Visible = false;
                        lbldatafound.Visible = true;
        //added the repeater to display the list of puja

                            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            String id = dt.Rows[i]["id"].ToString();
                            string query = "select puja.id,puja.name as puja_name, mandir.name as mandir_name from puja,mandir where mandir.id= puja.with_mandir and puja.with_mandir = '" + id + "'";
                            conn.Open();
                            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
                            MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                            adp.Fill(dt1);
                            conn.Close();


                                if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    lblmandirpuja.Text = "Poja in " + dt1.Rows[0]["mandir_name"];
                                    foreach (RepeaterItem repeatItem in Repeater1.Items){

                                    Repeater1.DataSource = dt1;

                                    Repeater1.DataBind();
                                        }

                                }

                        }
                    }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblnodatafound.Visible = true;
                        lbldatafound.Visible=false;

                    }

        }
        }
```

Comment: You are assigning repeater data source inside a loop `for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)` thats why you have last value only

Comment: if i removed that for loop then only the first value is diplayed and i too have to remove the variable i so thats not possible since variable i is displaying the list of tables.....isn't there another possibility?????

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line:

```
if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
```

for something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
```

And this one:

```
lblmandirpuja.Text = "Poja in " + dt1.Rows[0]["mandir_name"];
```

The 0 for the i:

```
lblmandirpuja.Text = "Poja in " + dt1.Rows[i]["mandir_name"];
```

Comment: its not working since whenever i keep o instead of i it results the first value's data ..since 0 represents first temples name list and 1 represents second's temple list respectively....can u plz suggest another answer?????

Comment: Oh ok, I realized that you are not using in the foreach (the foreach (RepeaterItem repeatItem in Repeater1.Items)) the repeatItem, maybe the error is in that point.

Comment: i have already deleted foreach (RepeaterItem repeatItem in Repeater1.Items).that part its of no use

Comment: But let me get clear. Datasource get some IEnumerable as parameter, then, do something like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/z16c79x4(v=vs.110).aspx. Then, first fill the datatable (dt1).